# QuickHull worst case

Tags: matlab, convex-hull, numerical-computing, qhull

[QHull](http://www.qhull.org) (and perhaps other good implementations of [QuickHull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickHull)) works really well and fast in many cases. However, we know theoretically that its worst case can be O(n^2). In practice I have not seen any numerical example with many dimensions (i.e., 20 or 100) where QHull works poorly.

Do you know of a numerical example where QHull works poorly, or gives the wrong result, or whatever that shows it cannot be applied here.

Comment: You mean "many data points", right? AFAIK quickhull is for two-dimensional data only. – According to Wikipedia, worst case is O(n²), O(n log n) is average.

Comment: Wikipedia: "processing usually becomes slow in cases of high symmetry or points lying on the circumference of a circle"

Comment: Either way, many data points, and / or many dimension.
Actually that is correct that worst case is O(n^2). Thanks. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

For multidimensional cases you have to generalize what A. Donda said: Generate a set of Points P with norm(p)==1 for each Point p in P. The convex hull is P (unless two points are identical) and will result in a bad running time of ~O(n^2)

For the 2D Case this will choose points on a circle, for 3D points on a sphere.